# If two densities are absolutly continuous are they equal a.s.?

Tags: probability, random-variables

let $p(dx)$ and $q(dx)$ two densities of representing two $L^1(\mathbb{P})$ random variables: $P$ and $Q$

if $p(x) = 0$ $=>$ $q(x)=0$ then is $P=Q$ in law ?

my intuition is based on Radon Nickodym's theorem wich will assure existance of a function $f$ s.t. $\forall B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$
$\int_B q(x)dx = \int_B f(x)p(x)dx$

but then this would imply $ f \equiv 1$ since q is a density and so  $q = p$ a.s. (by a density argument or whatever)?

Comment: If e.g. $p$ only takes positive values then the condition is satisfied, but there is no reason at all to think that $P=Q$ a.s.

Comment: yes you are absolutly right it was equality in law sorry for the typo

Comment: You write $q(B)=\int_Bf(x)p(x)dx$, leaving the impression that $q$ is a function on sets. But it is a density, isn't it? Densities induce probability measures (functions on sets) but are not probability measures themselves. Did you mean something like $\int_Bq(x)dx=\int_Bf(x)p(x)dx$ maybe?

Comment: this is an abuse of notation

Comment: but yes in deed it's what i ment

Comment: Well, as long as that is not mentioned it is very confusing. Why not being fully clear in it?

Comment: sorry it was clear for me indeed it's not usually used as a notation,I will make an edit to improve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $P \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $Q \sim \mathcal{N}(0,2)$. Then obviously we have absolute continuity in both ways but we do not have $p(x)=q(x)$ $\lambda$-a.e. where $\lambda$ stands for the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: yes your reasoning works indeed so i must have missed something

Comment: The expression "$p(x)=q(x)$ a.e." gives the impression that some measure must be working on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B)$. Else the abbreviation "a.e." would make no sense. Which measure did you have in mind?

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand the motivation behind your question @drhab. The abreviation would make no sense for the $\sigma$-algebra for Lebesgue measurable sets ?

Comment: In general expressions like $f=g$ a.e. stand for: $\mu(\{x\mid f(x)=g(x)\}=0$ where $\mu$ denotes a measure (or $\{x\mid f(x)=g(x)\}\subseteq A$ where $A$ is measurable and $\mu(A)=0$). So in the absence of any measure it makes no sense at all to say that $f=g$ a.e.. This justifies my question: what measure are you talking about here?

Comment: As it is written in wikipedia :"When discussing sets of real numbers, the Lebesgue measure is assumed unless otherwise stated.". But I will edit to make things clear.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the two distributions are equal equivalent (or one is absolutely continuous wrt the other) does not tell you anything about the random variables.
You could just take two variables with the *same* density which are not a.s. equal.

What maybe you were looking for is the following result.

Take a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, with some random variable $X$ defined on it. Assume that the law of $X$ under $\mathbb{P}$ is $\mu$. If you have another distribution $\nu << \mu$ such that 
$\nu(dx) = \mu(dx) \lambda(x)$, then you can find a probability measure $\mathbb{Q}$ on $\Omega$ such that the law of $X$ under $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\nu$.
This probability measure $\mathbb{Q}$ is given by
$$
\mathbb{Q}(A) = \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}} \mathbb{I}_A\lambda(X)
$$